# Are Tor .onion-addresses IP address independent?

Tags: lightning-network, tor, channels

Is it possible to move the node to a different IP address and keep the existing (=preciously open and funded) channels functional?

Comment: Can you double check your grammar? I think there is a to too much and that confuses me. Other that that changing your internet Adress works and keeps channels open

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The channels are announced with the node ID. If the ip Address changes we get a new node announcement message so it takes some time until the information is through the gossip protocol. But moving a node to a new server is no problem